# Adding textfiles when button is clicked Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am working on a functionality regarding a button click, where my requirement is I have only one button, if a button is clicked 1st time add a label, if same button is clicked for 2nd time add another label, like 5 time button is clicked 5 labels should be added.

```
-(IBAction) btnAddClicked: (id) sender {
    if (_btnAdd.tag == 0) {
        _lblAdd1.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (_btnAdd.tag == 1) {
        _lblAdd2.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (_btnAdd.tag == 2) {
        _lblAdd3.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (_btnAdd.tag == 3) {
        _lblAdd4.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried!

Comment: Do you have 5 labels in stroyboard already?

Comment: Yes, i need to display them with button clicks

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine which button is sending the event

```
-(IBAction)btnAddClicked: (id) sender {
    //Typecast to retrieve tag of current button.
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton * ) sender;
    if (btn.tag == 0) {
        _lblAdd1.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (btn.tag == 1) {
        _lblAdd2.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (btn.tag == 2) {
        _lblAdd3.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (btn.tag == 3) {
        _lblAdd4.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: am not getting it right, always btn.tag==0 is executed

Comment: It just means that you're not setting the button tag properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can update tag based on clicks.if you want more than one you can continue or else last click you set button tag as 0.

-(IBAction)btnAddClicked: (id) sender {

UIButton *btn = (UIButton * ) sender;

```
if (btn.tag == 0) {
    _lblAdd1.hidden = YES;
    btn.tag = 1;
}
else if (btn.tag == 1) {
    _lblAdd2.hidden = YES;
    btn.tag = 2;
}
else if (btn.tag == 2) {
    _lblAdd3.hidden = YES;
    btn.tag = 3;
}
else if (btn.tag == 3) {
    _lblAdd4.hidden = YES;
    btn.tag = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for n number of dynamic textfields creation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _count; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TextViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell; }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"Add TextField" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(addTextField) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[footerView addSubview:button];
return footerView;  }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 30;  }

-(void)addTextField{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_count inSection:0];
_count++;
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; }
```

Comment: Question is tagged with _objective-c_ and not _swift_.

Answer (score 0):

to ways to do this
1 Use TableView who's cell contains a textFld , each time when you click the button, Update the UITableView By Number of cells one more the last count ..
Example : On first Click add indexPath/number/etc to a mutable array and reload the the tableview for count of that array, table cell will create for one cell ..
Now On second click add one more to that array and reload the tableview, now tableview will create cells for the array count which is now 2 ... SO On. hope you are getting it

Comment: 2. Use UIStackView and on each click create a UITextFld and It as Subview for that stackView ..